Reference request for characteristic subgroups of free abelian groups
The characteristic subgroups of a free abelian group $F$ are the $k F$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. (In particular, they are verbal and hence fully invariant.) I know a proof when $F$ has finite rank, but I would like to know a reference of this fact in the literature, which has the proof. (In a paper I am working on I prefer to not write down the proof.)
Sketch of the proof when $F$ has finite rank, say $F=\mathbb{Z}^n$: one knows that $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ are conjugated under $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ iff $\mathrm{gcd}(u_1,\dotsc,u_n) = \mathrm{gcd}(v_1,\dotsc,v_n)$. If $U \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n$ is characteristic and $u \in U$ has $\mathrm{gcd}(u_1,\dotsc,u_n) = k$, it follows $k e_1,\dotsc,k e_n \subseteq U$ and hence $k \mathbb{Z}^n \subseteq U$. Now $\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \mathbb{Z}^n \subseteq U\}$ is a subgroup, and a generator of this subgroup does the job.

Or you could use the structure theorem for modules over a PID and consider the automorphisms that permute the coordinates.

Ok maybe the real name of the fact I'm thinking about is different, but I meant the characterization of submodules of a finitely generated module over a PID. I know you are looking for a reference, but this is such a trivial consequence of this fact that you may just say that it follows from that, I guess.

Which classification do you mean exactly?

Given a finitely generated free module $M$ over a PID and a submodule $N$, there exist a base ${v_1,\dots, v_n}$ for $M$ and coefficients ${a_1,\dots, a_k}$ such that ${a_1v_1,\dots ,a_kv_k}$ is a base for $N$. If you permute the coordinates you find that the $a_i$'s are all associated, hence you have the thesis.

Thanks. That's right. I just noticed that the claim should also be true for general free abelian groups. There I assume that we cannot use the structure theorem.

EDIT: The results in this answer appear to be insufficient to qualify as a proper answer. I'm leaving this answer up as it is too long for a comment and possibly of interest to anyone interested in this question.
This result is mentioned as "well known" (without giving a reference, sadly), and used to prove a stronger result in the following paper. A free, legal scan is available here.
Göbel, Rüdiger, The characteristic subgroups of the Baer-Specker group, Math. Z. 140, 289-292 (1974). ZBL0281.20026.
The introduction is pretty self-explanatory:

It is well known, that the only characteristic subgroups of a free abelian
group $A$ are the subgroups $n \cdot A$ for all integers $n \geqq 0$. We will show that this is true for a larger class of groups, namely for all $\mathbf{K}$-direct sums $\bigoplus_{\mathbf{K}} \mathbb{Z}$ of infinite
cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbf{K}$ is an ideal of an arbitrary power set. In particular it is true for arbitrary cartesian powers $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbf{I}}$.

Alternatively, GroupProps has the following two articles:

Verbal subgroup equals power subgroup in abelian group,
Characteristic equals verbal in free abelian group.

Combining these two results gives you what you want, though unfortunately the latter article doesn't include a proof. Moreover, no references are given in these articles, nor was I able to find these results anywhere else.

Unfortunately the linked proof uses the special case of free abelian groups. So this is not what I can use.

@MartinBrandenburg You're absolutely right, I missed that the proof uses the weaker result. I've edited the answer to mention this. I've also issued a new bounty, in hopes of attracting a proper answer.

Your proof for finite rank free abelian groups works almost verbatim for general free abelian groups.
Proof of statement for general free abelian groups:
Let $U\subseteq \oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}$ be a characteristic subgroup, where $I$ is some (possibly infinite) set. Let $e_i$, $i\in I$ generate the summands of $\oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}$.
For $u \in U$ let $\gcd(u)$ denote the greatest common divisor of the coefficients on the the $e_i$ for $u$.
Any $u\in U$ satisfies $$u\in \oplus_{i\in A} \mathbb{Z}\subseteq \oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z},$$ where $A$ is a finite subset of $I$, and the inclusion of groups is induced by the inclusion of sets $A\subseteq I$.
Then by encoding the steps in Euclid's algorithm applied to $u$ as matrices, we obtain an automorphism of $\oplus_{i\in A} \mathbb{Z}$ which maps $$u\mapsto gcd(u)e_j,$$
for some $j\in A$.  This automorphism extends to an automorphism of $\oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}$, using $I=A\sqcup (I\backslash A)$.  Then for any $k\in I$, some permutation of $I$ will map $j\mapsto k$, inducing an automorphism of $\oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}$, mapping $e_j\mapsto e_k$.  Composing these automorphisms, we map $$u\mapsto \gcd(u)e_k.$$
Thus for all $u\in U$, we have $\gcd(u)\left(\oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}\right)\subseteq U$.  Thus $$\gcd\{\gcd(u)|u\in U\}\left(\oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}\right)\subseteq U.$$
Conversely, given $u\in U$, we have $$\gcd\{\gcd(u)|u\in U\}\,\,|\,\, \gcd(u),$$ so
$$U\subseteq \gcd\{\gcd(u)|u\in U\}\left(\oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}\right).$$

Oh yes, I should have seen that. Thanks. I am still looking for a proper reference though.

@MartinBrandenburg Something I have done in the past is reference answers on stackexchange.  In my case it was for a passing observation unrelated to  my main arguments, but another situation where it could be OK to reference something that has not been peer-reviewed is for a result considered "well-known".
